# Cross-section of a wave packet

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, waves

In text books, wave packets are one-dimensional drawings. But we live in a three-dimensional world. Suppose a wave packet from a HI-cloud (frequency 1420 MHz) is approaching the earth, distance about 10 million miles and it will arrive here in a few seconds. How long is this packet (FWHM)? How large is the cross-section? Is the diameter zero? Or 1/10 of a wavelength or three time the wavelength? Or even bigger?

Any good ideas?

(This question is partly inspired by [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/3540/2451) Phys.SE answer.)

Comment: What is your definition of a wave packet?

Answer (score 1):

Light doesn't naturally clump into "wave packets" (it does tend to clump up onto single vibrational modes of the electromagnetic field, but these aren't necessarily spatially localized). As a general rule you only get something like that if you intentionally make it with a laser. In that case, the geometric properties of the packet can be whatever you want them to be (subject to Maxwell's equations and your skill with a laser).

In the case of something emitted from a cloud, the distribution of emitted light would be roughly spherically symmetric. This means that if it were 1 light year away, the "cross section" would be $4 \pi$ square light years.

#### Short answer:

There are no limits on the size of a wave packet in either the longitudinal or transverse directions. It can be arbitrarily big or (almost) arbitrarily small (there are uncertainty relations) depending on the circumstances that led to it's formation.

Comment: That would mean, that the expression "wave packet" is meaningless, if one talks of a single particle like a photon? Surprise, surprise. How many photons (electrons, neutrons,...) are neccessary to form a wave packet? Surely, in the moment of emission, every direction has the same probability. That was not my question. herbert

Comment: @9herbert9: You have to remember that photons are quantum objects: the number of photons can be in superposition. It's possible to have a wave packet with an expectation value of the photon number operator less than 1. See [here](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v484/n7392/full/nature10920.html) for an example. Any number or superposition of numbers of photons can form a wave packet except exactly zero.

Comment: @9herbert9: Answering this, I thought that you thought that wave packets correspond to individual photons. You *can* have one-photon wave packets (with the caveat that there's an uncertainty relation between photon number and phase, so it's going to look weird).

Comment: The Mirrors in the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrabri_Stellar_Intensity_Interferometer (see http://olbin.jpl.nasa.gov/photos/nsii.html) are about 30 m apart and receive parts of the same wave packet. What would happen, if the distance ist doubled? herbert

Comment: @9herbert9: Then they would have a longer baseline and better spatial resolution.

Comment: ..and nothing changes? You may lengthen the baseline as far as you want without destroying the clearness of the interference pattern? That would mean, in the Double-slit experiment with *incoherent* light you may choose any distance between the slits? Why do the use lasers, if a simple light bulb will do the job as well? herbert

Comment: @9herbert9: The NSII is a Hanbury-Brown and Twiss interferometer, and it doesn't resemble a double slit interferometer very much. Also, the distance between slits (and the size of slits) you need in a double slit interferometer is determined by the *wavelength*  of the light, not any of it's transverse properties.

Comment: @9herbert9: "in the Double-slit experiment with incoherent light you may choose any distance between the slits?" "Incoherent" light is only phase-incoherent. Chaotic light (what you get from stars) is actually *maximally* coherent in photon number. Photon number and phase are conjugate quantities, like position and momentum, and can't both be known to arbitrary precision.

Comment: @9herbert9: "Why do the use lasers, if a simple light bulb will do the job as well?": Lasers and light bulbs are a different kind of coherent. You use lasers when you need phase coherence, and you can use a light bulb or the sun when you need photon number coherence.

Comment: @9herbert9: Quantum optics is a crazy subject :). I don't know at what level you're studying physics, but if you're at an advanced undergraduate level I'd suggest [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Elements-Quantum-Optics-Pierre-Meystre/dp/3642093523/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1373220664&sr=8-1&keywords=meystre+quantum+optics). It's a bit expensive, so you might want to see if your library has a copy first.