# Strangeness of QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In quantum field theory, the particle-wave duality is resolved by assuming that a field can collapse to some quantum value. Suppose you are observing a distant star through a small aperture that allows only one photon at a time to strike a detector. According to the QFT formalism, the field required to instantaneously collapse to a photon of energy hf would subtend a transverse waveform area having a diameter in the order of light years. Does this type of instantaneous collapse in QFT violate special relativity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Photon wave packets from distant stars](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3531/photon-wave-packets-from-distant-stars)

Answer (score 3):

Let me attempt to rephrase what I think you're asking:

> Suppose a star emits light with a frequency $\nu$ so the energy per photon is $h\nu$. Suppose further that the emission is spherically symmetric so the energy emitted by the star is evenly spread over all $4\pi$ steradians. If we go far enough away from the star the intensity of the light is so low that the photon energy $hv$ is spread over a region of space many light years in size. In that case how can we detect a photon since the energy for the photon would have to travel light years to the point where the photon is detected?

Assuming I have understood you correctly the answer is that prior to detection the photon is in a superposition of all possible positions. The detection collapses the superposition and localises the photon at the point of detection.

It's tempting to think of the photon energy as being spread out in the way we might spread out a fluid, but this would be to misunderstand what is going on. The photon energy doesn't have a position, in the same way that (to take a more familiar example) the electron in a hydrogen atom doesn't have a position. It exists in a superposition of all positions. When the photon was detected its energy didn't have to travel to the detection point because it was already there.

Comment: I have a small difficulty with the word "collapse" in this context.  If the field has more than one quantum of excitation, then after one quantum is removed the remaining quanta are still delocalized.  It seems to me that the wave function has not collapsed.  I recognize that you did *not* say that the wave function collapses, but rather you say that the superposition collapses, but I'm not sure what you mean exactly.  My picture, which might be equivalent to yours, is that the wave function does not collapse, but the interaction occurs at a specific location.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding quantum field theory. The entire wave doesn't collapse, in the same way that a flashlight doesn't shoot out one big photon. The star emits many photons, of which you see one in this scenario. By the way, this isn't QFT, but instead, more general QM.